# How to enable Virtual ListView Control for OpenLDAP server?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm trying to use UnboundID's LDAP SDK to fetch contacts present on an LDAP server.
I'm using the VirtualListView(VLV) Control along with Server-side sort in my code and this code works perfectly fine when I tested with a LDAP server configured in my organization.

However, I wanted to setup a local server and add certain contacts/entries to it and test my code with that server. For this, I used OpenLDAP and configured it on Ubuntu 10.04 using instructions from this link: http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/31/set-up-your-ldap-server-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Now, when I tried getting the contacts, my code does not work as the server I've setup is not supporting VLV. When I perform a simple search, i.e. without any VLV or other paging technique, then I am able to see the results. This means the server is working fine, but not supporting VLV control.

So what I need to know is how can I enable support for VLV or any other required controls for my server?

Please do let me know if anyone knows how to achieve this. Hors of googling hasn't lead to any promising results :(

Thanks & Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is off topic, should be on serverfault.com, but you have to load, enable, and configure the SSSVLV overlay.

Forget that blog, and all random Internet blogs while you're at it. Have a good look at the [OpenLDAP Admin Guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc) itself, which is where you should have started. I can also recommend a really good reference [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/), but only because I've used it extensively, not just because Google said so.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know about the serverfault site and neither that this question is not supposed to be here on SO.

Actually, I left this part and just used my organization's LDAPServer as it was becoming too complicated for me to understand...probably because I've never had any experience with LDAP servers and their setup/configuration.
Anyways, thanks for the links.. others may find them useful in case they have questions like me. :)